# only heat a URI, not wait for responce in Spring Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

Suppose I click on URI `localhost:8080/admin/hello` with `Hello` class POST JSON object using POSTMAN and have a Controller like,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Hello> helloHome(@RequestBody Hello obj){
//here it goes to service class and doing processes...
return new ResponseEntity<Hello>(obj, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I only want the URI to hit the Controller but not wait for response (because processing all the service class process takes 10 seconds but I want to return immediate without response).

How can I implement it?

Comment: Do you want the processing to be done or not??.do you expect any result from processing?

Comment: Thanks to Quick reply, here i want only heat URI with Object saved or not i do not want any response. i only want quick return without any object. and i also check `Void`  but it also take time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable Async processing by enabling it via your config.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class YourConfig
```

Now you can add a service and enable async processing on one of its methods by annotating it with `@Async`. It will return immediately after it was called.

```
@Async
public void asyncMethodOnAService() {}
```

If you want to service to return a value you can return a `CompletableFuture`

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<String> asyncMethodOnAService() {}
```

The controller that call the async method can return a `DeferredResult` which will let the client know that the result will be available once the async processing has finished.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/async", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> doAsync() {

      DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> result = new DeferredResult<>();
      this.asyncService.asyncMethodOnAService().whenComplete((serviceResult, throwable) -> result.setResult(ResponseEntity.ok(serviceResult)));

      return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Move all the processing logic to Service class(if you haven't already) and annotate your service class method with `@Async`. This will make the method call to be executed in a separate thread and controller method won't wait for the service class method completion.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Hello> helloHome(@RequestBody Hello obj){
  helloHomeService.processRequest(obj);
  return new ResponseEntity<Hello>(obj, HttpStatus.OK);
}

public Class HomeService{
@Async
public void processRequest(Hello obj){
  //processing logic
}
```

}

Comment: hello Thanks for Answer, here you can guide me. when we create separate thread for each service. Is this threads stop automatically or stopped manually by Handling ...

Comment: You aren't creating thread explicitly. The `@Async` annotation does that for you. It'll stop automatically once it's execution completes. One more thing to note, you'll have to use `@EnableAsync` on your application class.

Answer (score 1):

you can enable Async by using @EnableAsync:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
class AsyncConfig{}

@Component  //in order to be scanned
class YourService{
@Async
public void asyncMethod(args){}
}
}

in your controller:
@Autowired
private YourService service;
....

public ResponseEntity<Hello> helloHome(@RequestBody Hello obj){
  service.asyncMethode(params);
  return new ResponseEntity<Hello>(obj, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```